# Problems trying to deploy Laravel 9 app on Ubuntu Server 20.04

Tags: 20.04, apache2, php, application-development, laravel

Im facing problems while try to deploy my **Laravel App (v9)** on my **Ubuntu Server**.

First of all, Im going to share my **Apache Configuration** because I think my problem is related with it more than Laravel.

My project name is **cv_backend**

Well, my web projects are in `/var/www/html/.` Im trying to deploy my new app name called **cv**. So my apache configuration in `sites-enabled/000-default.conf` is :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        
       Redirect "/cv_backend" "https://my-dns/cv_backend"


        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        <Directory /var/www/html/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>


        <Directory /var/www/html/cv_backend/public>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Multiviews
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>


        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <IfModule mod_dir.c>
            DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.html index.xhtml index.htm
        </IfModule>
        
        Alias /cv_backend '/var/www/html/cv_backend/public'



</VirtualHost>
```

My app is located in : `/var/www/html/cv_backend`. But when I try to access to my app I only can see the filesystem of project :

[image]

For other part, `.htaccess` of my laravel app is :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase '/cv_backend'

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

As  you can see I **rewrite** base path to app name (cv_backend).

I think is related about wrong path public laravel app is detected, but I dont know why.

Finally I must to say, I have php 7.* and I upgraded to 8.1 in order to deploy new version laravel projects. I think there is no problem with this new installation, I tested `php artisan tinker` and work fine!

But I dont understand why dont load my app correctlly.

---

## Update. Replying. `@matigo`

I have create a single config file for my project as `@matigo` mentioned, here my file (`cv_backend.conf`) :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        Redirect "/cv_backend" "https://mi-servidor.ddns.net/cv_backend"


        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/cv_backend/public


        <Directory /var/www/html/cv_backend/public>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Multiviews
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>


        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <IfModule mod_dir.c>
            DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.html index.xhtml index.htm
        </IfModule>


        Alias /cv_backend '/var/www/html/cv_backend/public'


</VirtualHost>
```

But still facing the same problem. (I called commands to apply configuration : `a2ensite cv_backend.conf` but still nothing work )

Comment: Your `DocumentRoot` value in the Apache configuration file should be `/var/www/html/cv_backend/public`. Be sure to restart Apache after updating the file, then you should be good.

Comment: Thank for answaer, but I have multiple projects, I think if i do that I can only access to this project, I use alias to manage multiple apps on same apache

Comment: Ideally one would have a single Apache configuration per project. This would allow for better isolation so that configuring one does not destroy all 

Comment: @matigo I have replied you updating my question. But still doesnt work :(